# php how to read word document with text and images

Tags: php

is there any easy tool for reading text and images in a MS word document with php. is it possible?

Here is an example of the document:

```
Some text
Some text
---------
| Image |
---------
Some text
```

how can i get the text and the image in order?

Comment: Using a library like [PHPWord](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord)

Comment: @MarkBaker oh, doesnt it help only creating or editing the document?

Comment: RTFM - It can READ as well (otherwise how could it possibly edit?).... `PHPWord is a library written in pure PHP that provides a set of classes to write to AND READ FROM different document file formats.`

Comment: .... ok then thank you

Comment: Not able to read images from docx

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PHPWord](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord) (which is part of [PHPOffice](http://phpoffice.github.io/))

> PHPWord is a library written in pure PHP that provides a set of classes to **write to and read from** different document file formats. The current version of PHPWord supports Microsoft Office Open XML (OOXML or OpenXML), OASIS Open Document Format for Office Applications (OpenDocument or ODF), Rich Text Format (RTF), HTML, and PDF.